# How to map every item from an object with an unknown amount of items, or item names in a reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to build reusable components. For a personal project, I'm trying to map items fetched from a database, but I want it to be able to take in any number of non-predetermined types and map them as table elements. For this scenario, I'm using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

The following code works, but only if I tell it what it's mapping from the database. Ideally, I want it to be able to map all the items from the object without labels such as "id" or "name".

```
    export interface Table {
        postInfo: Array<Post>;
    }
    export interface Post {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }

    export default (props: { postInfo<Post> }) => {
        const { postInfo } = props;

    return (
        <table items={postInfo}>
            {postInfo.map(content=> (
                <tr>
                    <td>{content.id}</td>
                    <td>{content.name}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    )
   }
```

This functions as I expect it to. But I want to make it reusable so in the future, I can use something like "username" or "phone number" and have it still map through the object, returning table elements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that Using: `Object.values()`
For Example:

```
const c = { id: 1, name: 'any' };
console.log(Object.values(c)) //returns an array: [1, 'any']
```

We can iterate though the values for each key in an object, for you, this would be like:

```
        <table items={postInfo}>
            {
              postInfo.map(content=> (
                <tr>
                  {
                    Object
                      .values(content)
                      .map(val => (
                        <td>{val}</td>
                      ))
                  }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately this does virtually the same thing my code already does unless I'm missing what you're trying to do with this. You're setting the table data to {content.id}, I don't want there to be any specific handle (id), I want it to map through every item in the object regardless of what's in the object.

Comment: Sorry for this, as it's quick but it was missing, I have updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

General idea is to pass in the column (you can even define the column text and field name) as follow: (did not run it... might have minor errors)

```
export interface Table {
    postInfo: Array<Post>;
}
export interface Post {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export default (props: { postInfo<Post>, columns }) => {
    const { postInfo, columns } = props;

return (
    <table items={postInfo}>
        {postInfo.map(content=> (
            <tr>
                {columns.map(column => (<td>{content[column]</td>)}
            </tr>
    </table>
)
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Can't we get all the keys of json response you are getting from the db and just iterate through all the keys getting their values ?

Comment: Hi there, Stack Overflow Community guidlines and rules are strict to this kind of `answer`. if you are not able to answer the question and you require that the author give more information you can ask him by commenting on the post itself.

Comment: @SultanH. commenting needs 50 rep. OP, once you have enough rep, you'll be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, you can still ask, answer (with a solution) or suggest edit to get reputation.

Comment: I didn't actually know that, thanks @EmileBergeron!